# What are the major changes from BO XI R3 and BO XI R4?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, sap-bw

I am doing some research and i'm interested in what others may think of it:
For whom have access to BO XI r4, what are in your opinion the major changes in the new releases?

Is it worth upgrading ?

Does it improve integration with existing SAP BW installations?

Any insight will be very helpful!
Thank you

Fabio Prevedelli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find answer, for your question regarding new features in r4, check these two posts : http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/23631 and http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/23250 on SCN (SAP Community Network). Yes the integration is improved:

> SAP Info Cubes using BEx queries: You can build Bex queries just like building a query in a universe.

I have an access to r4 but I use it in a small project so I do not have occasion to use all the new features. For me, the most striking were improvements in UI and tools (Information design tool!), and Dashboard Design.

EDIT: [here](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/bi-suite-tutorials?refer=marketing) you will find click-by-click tutorials, so you can get see what is new.